# How to Group property in Order Clause using Grails Criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails

i am using Grails Criteria to pull results for a specific domaini want to ask whether is it possible to have group property in order clause or in other words, how can i write following mysql query  using Grails criteria ?

```
select 
       h.name,
       count(h.id) 
from my_table as h 
group by h.name 
order by count(h.id) desc;
```

so far grails criteria query looks like

```
def results =  MyObject.createCriteria().list{

 projections{
     groupProperty('name')
     countDistinct('id')

  }
   order(???,'desc')
}
```

Thanks in advance
Rehman

Comment: answer was quite easy, one need to create alias for count function

e.g
`
select 
       h.name,
       count(h.id)  as countDist
from my_table as h 
group by h.name 
order by countDist desc;`

and grails criteria for aforementioned query
`
def results =  MyObject.createCriteria().list{

 projections{
     groupProperty('name')
     countDistinct('id', 'countDist')

  }
   order('countDist ','desc')
}`

cheers

Comment: Might want to add this comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered this problem. Just to clarify Rehman's answer.

```
 def results =  MyObject.createCriteria().list {

    projections {
       groupProperty('name')
       countDistinct('id', 'idDistinct')
    }
    order('idDisctinct','desc')
 }
```